# Unable to fetch data from Nested Array URL and populate List

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm attempting to fetch data from a URL. There are two arrays that I am parsing through to get to the info that I need, in this case, wait_times (link via [queue-times.com](https://queue-times.com/parks/16/queue_times.json)). The data is parsed like so:

[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML9C0.png)

[image: Simulator View]

Below is my method for retrieving the data. I'm attempting to make the call through the arrays, and then displaying the results in a list. There doesn't appear to be an API_KEY that I need to use, but definitely I need to display the message Powered by Queue-Times.com that links to https://queue-times.com/en-US. Is that all that is required for my info to populate?

```
import SwiftUI

struct Wrapper: Decodable {
    let lands: [Land]
}

struct Land: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var rides: [RideTime]
}

struct RideTime: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var is_open: String
    var wait_time: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var lands = [Land]()
    @State private var rideTime = [RideTime]()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(rideTime, id: \.id) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.name)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .accentColor(.white)
                    Text(item.wait_time)
                        .font(.body)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Ride Wait Times")
            .task {
                await fetchData()
            }
        } // NavigationView
    }
    
    func fetchData() async {
        // create URL
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://queue-times.com/parks/16/queue_times.json") else {
            print("Didn't find any fun stuff :(")
            return
        }
        
        // fetch data from URL
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            // decode data
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([RideTime].self, from: data) {
                rideTime = decodedResponse
            }
        } catch {
            print("This data is no-can-see")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I've attempted to create a struct for each array and iterate through each one, but it appears there may be some error in them. Or, perhaps the link.

Comment: Put print(error) in the catch

Comment: And remove `try?`, it's the worst thing you can use when you're having some issue related to decoding json

Comment: `is_open` is `Bool` and `wait_time` is `Int`.  The compiler will tell you that if you catch the DecodingError which is pretty silly not to do. And you should map the snake case keys to camel case struct members.

Comment: … and you have to decode the JSON from the top level which means `Wrapper.self` rather than `[RideTime].self`.

Comment: Please do not post images of text (JSON). Please replace the image link with the actual JSON text. The text in images can't be copied or referenced and it is harder to read. It's also harder to post.